# How to use the 'perfcurve' of Matlab with specific inputs?

Tags: matlab, roc

I wrote following codes to get a plot of 'classification accuracy' vs. 'threshold':

(The datasets has the ground truth contains two classes labelled 'Good' or 'Bad')

```
LDAClassifierObject                     = ClassificationDiscriminant.fit(featureSelcted, groundTruthGroup, 'DiscrimType', 'linear');
[LDALabel, LDAScore]                    = resubPredict(LDAClassifierObject);

[~, AccuracyLDA, Thr]                   = perfcurve(groundTruthNumericalLable(:,1), LDAScore(:,1), 1,'yCrit','accu');
figure,
plot(Thr,AccuracyLDA,'r-');
hold on;
plot(Thr,AccuracyLDA,'bo');
xlabel('Threshold for ''good'' Returns');
ylabel('Classification Accuracy');
grid on;

[maxVal, maxInd] = max(AccuracyLDA)

maxVal =

    0.8696

maxInd =

    15

Thr(15)

ans =

    0.7711
```

Also, I run the ROC analysis for the same datasets that the ground truth contains two classes labelled 'Good' or 'Bad'

```
[FPR, TPR, Thr, AUC, OPTROCPT]      = perfcurve(groundTruthGroup(:,1), LDAScore(:,1), 'Good');

OPTROCPT =

    0.1250    0.8667
```

Why `Thr(15)=0.7711` is different from `OPTROCPT(2)=0.8667`?

Is the best cut-off point (ie, the best threshold OPTROCPT) obtained by ROC is the one has maximum accuracy of LDA?

Or maybe I am wrong, then what exactly `perfcurve(groundTruthNumericalLable(:,1), LDAScore(:,1), 1,'yCrit','accu')` tell us?